# BigQuery: Load avro-files with date column data type as long converted to timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery, avro, bq

I have troubles getting BigQuery to load timestamps from avro-files correctly.

The avro-files have date columns stored as long, with logical type timestamp-micros. As per documentation, BigQuery should store this as timestamp data type. I have also tried timestamp-millis for logical type.

The data is stored in avro like this:

```
{'id': '<masked>', '<masked>': '<masked>', 'tm': 1553990400000, '<masked>': <masked>, '<masked>': <masked>, 'created': 1597056958864}
```

The fields *tm* and *created* are longs, *2019-03-31T00:00:00Z* and *2020-08-10T11:50:58.986816592Z* respectively.

The schema for the avro is

```
{"type":"record","name":"SomeMessage","namespace":"com.df",
"fields":
[{"name":"id","type":"string"},
{"name":"<masked>","type":"string"},
{"name":"tm","type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-micros"},
{"name":"<masked>","type":"int"},
{"name":"<masked>","type":"float"},
{"name":"created","type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-micros"}]}";
```

When imported to BigQuery through *bq load*, records ends up like these:

```
<masked>   <masked>   tm                            <masked>   <masked>  created
________________________________________________________________________________________________________
<masked> | <masked> | 1970-01-18 23:39:50.400 UTC | <masked> | <masked> | 1970-01-19 11:37:36.958864 UTC
________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The import command used is:

```
bq load --source_format=AVRO --use_avro_logical_types some_dataset.some_table "gs://some-bucket/some.avro"
```

The timestamps in BigQuery are nowhere near the actual values provided in avro.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this properly?

Comment: It seems data 1553990400000 & 1597056958864 are in millis. Try passing micro seconds or use `timestamp-millis` instead of `timestamp-micros` in schema.

Comment: Logical attributes are ignored by default, for backward compatibility reasons as logical types were not initially supported, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#logical_types. Did you enable useAvroLogicalTypes?

Comment: I did enable useAvroLogicalTypes. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Ambrish, using `timestamp-millis` produces same results as `timestamp-micros`. Its almost like BigQuery is not seeing the logicaltype information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that the avro schema is actually wrong.
The timestamp fields should be like this:

```
{"name":"created","type":{"type":"long", "logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}}
```